# Manipulating x axis tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, bar-chart

I have noticed that when I have 5 or less bars of data in my bar graph the x-axis automatically adds in extra ticks:
[image]
What I want is something like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can force matplotlib to generate just one tick label per bar for the first graph?

Comment: it also looks like you have discovered the unicode bug in matplotlib on OSX [issue 1737](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1737) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524662/matplotlib-mac-osx-10-8-cuts-off-tick-and-axes-labels

Comment: It is also _very_ helpful if you show us the code you used to generate these two graphs.  We can _guess_ how you did it, and what went wrong, but you will get more, faster, and better answers if we can _see_ what you are doing and then address it directly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `bar` method takes a parameter `align`. Set this parameter as `align='center'`. `align` aligns the bars on the center of the x values we give it, instead of aligning on the left side of the bar (which is the default).

Then use the `xticks` method to specify how many ticks on the x-axis and where to place them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

x = range(1, 7)
y = (0, 300, 300, 290, 320, 315)
plot.bar(x, y, width=0.7, align="center")

ind = range(2, 7)    # the x locations for the groups
plot.xticks(ind, x)

plot.axhline(305, linewidth=3, color='r')

plot.show()
```

Docs are at http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html